# Python pandas.DataFrame: Make whole row NaN according to condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make the whole row NaN according to a condition, based on a column. For example, if `B > 5`, I want to make the whole row NaN.

Unprocessed data frame looks like this:

```
   A  B
0  1  4
1  3  5
2  4  6
3  8  7
```

Make whole row NaN, if `B > 5`:

```
     A    B
0  1.0  4.0
1  3.0  5.0
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use `df.loc[df.B > 5, :] = np.nan`

---

Example

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
   A  B
0  1  4
1  3  5
2  4  6
3  8  7

In [15]: df.loc[df.B > 5, :] = np.nan 

In [16]: df
Out[16]: 
     A    B
0  1.0  4.0
1  3.0  5.0
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
```

in human language `df.loc[df.B > 5, :] = np.nan` can be translated to:

> assign `np.nan` to any column (`:`) of the dataframe ( `df` ) where the
>   condition `df.B > 5` is valid.

Comment: Ok, but `loc` is here redundant, what do you think?

Comment: @s900n I recommend accepting jezrael's answer as it covers more options, mine is here to complete the options ..

Answer (score 9):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for assign value per condition:

```
df[df['B'] > 5] = np.nan
print (df)
     A    B
0  1.0  4.0
1  3.0  5.0
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
```

Or [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) which add by default `NaN`s by condition:

```
df = df.mask(df['B'] > 5)
print (df)
     A    B
0  1.0  4.0
1  3.0  5.0
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
```

Thank you [Bharath shetty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46488530/python-pandas-dataframe-make-whole-row-nan-according-to-condition/46488571?noredirect=1#comment79936183_46488571):

```
df = df.where(~(df['B']>5))
```

Comment: One with `where` i.e `df.where(~(df['B']>5))`

Answer (score 0):

Or using `reindex`

```
df.loc[df.B<=5,:].reindex(df.index)
Out[83]: 
     A    B
0  1.0  4.0
1  3.0  5.0
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
```